iteration varieble outside tikz foreach loop with tkz-euclide
Example from doc of tkz-euclide:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \an [count=\i] in {0,60,...,300}
  { \tkzDefPoint(\an:3){A_\i}}
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A_1,A_...,A_6)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A_1,A_...,A_6)
\end{tikzpicture}

works fine.
But when changing to double varieble iteration:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i / \an in {1 / 0,2 / 60,3 / 120,4 / 180,5 / 240,6 / 300}
  { \tkzDefPoint(\an:3){A_\i} \tkzDrawPoint(A_\i)}
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A_1,A_...,A_6) %
  \tkzDrawPoints(A_1,A_...,A_6) % without the last 2 lines, 6 points will be drawn normally
\end{tikzpicture}

there is error: ! Package pgf Error: No shape named `A_1' is known.
It seems A_1-A_6 become invalid outside the loop.
Is it a bug in the underlying tikz or a bug in tkz-euclide?
I'm working on a more complicate tikzpicture so count=\i will not useful for me.

Remove the space between 1, 2, and so on and /. PGFFor doesn't remove it for you.

I see, thank you! @Qrrbrbirlbel

The spaces around / will not be stripped away so your coordinates are actually named A_1␣, A_2␣, etc.
Remove the spaces. (A space after a , or at the start will be ignored.)
I've also added an alternative where the angle is calculated instead of hard-coded. I'm sure tkz-euclide has functions to generate regular polygons automatically …
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\an in {1/0, 2/60, 3/120, 4/180, 5/240, 6/300}{
  \tkzDefPoint(\an:3){A_\i}
  \tkzDrawPoint(A_\i)
}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A_1,A_...,A_6)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\j from 0] \i in {1, ..., 6}{
  \tkzDefPoint(\j*60:3){A_\i}
  \tkzDrawPoint(A_\i)
}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A_1,A_...,A_6)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

